# How we can count the unique User ID that order in last three days per each day?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this table :

[image]

I need to count unique UserID in the last 3 days per each day like below :

[image]

- For example, on 5/5/2020 I need to count the unique user id that ordered in 5/3/2020 and 5/4/2020 and 5/5/2020. so we have 12 unique userID.
- On 5/4/2020 I need to count the unique user id that ordered in 5/2/2020 and 5/3/2020 and 5/4/2020. so we have 11 unique userID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  One method uses `apply`:

```
select d.orderdate, o2.num_users_3
from (select distinct o.orderdate from orders o) d cross apply
     (select count(distinct o2.userId) as num_users_3
      from orders o2
      where o2.orderdate <= d.orderdate and
            o2.orderdate > dateadd(day, -4, d.orderdate)
     ) o2;
```

Comment: Should you be referencing `d.orderdate` instead of `o.orderdate` in the predicate for the second inner subquery since you aliased the first subquery as 'd'?